# Replace attribute inside a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling to find a solution of replacing my attribute with another.

My HTML is:

```
<a href="#" external>link</a>
```

I want to replace "**external**" with **target="_blank"**

Is it doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for that.

Just iterate over the anchor elements with the `external` attribute using the selector `a[external]` and remove the `external` attribute and set the `target` attribute:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/t2wg0hnf/)

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[external]'), function(a) {
    a.removeAttribute('external');
    a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
});
```

---

For what it's worth, if you want the jQuery alternative, use:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/0pqaobua/)

```
$('a[external]').each(function () {
    $(this).removeAttr('external');
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this doesn't do what the OP describes, even if it does what he wanted. He said he wanted to replace external with target='_blank'. This removes external and adds target='_blank' **regardless of whether or not that anchor had an external attribute**. The below takes your code and checks for the existence of the external attribute before doing anything.

```
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(a) {
    if (a.getAttribute("external") != null) {
        a.removeAttribute('external');
        a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    }
});
```

Comment: An easier solution would be to just iterate over elements with the `external` attribute using the selector `a[external]`. I updated my answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You're correct. I knew jQuery had that, I wasn't sure if querySelectorAll supported it too. Good catch